# How to update an image in firebase storage?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am working on an image gallery app with **Angular** and I want to be able to execute **CRUD** operations on every image and its description. My images are stored in **the firebase storage**, the descriptions and image URLs are stored in **Firestore**.

I need to be able to **update** images and after that, I will change the image URL that I pass to the front-end, but I am only aware of the **upload** method for images.

**What is the best practice to update images in the storage?**

I thought of a workaround whereby I can delete the old image and upload the new one, but I hope there is a better way and a proper way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an update method. Sometimes the Firebase Firestore database will get updated before the image has been updated, so it is needed to put the Firestore function to run after this Firebase storage put method finishes. So it is needed to use the future method:

```
void uploadToStorage(CurrentUser user) {
  final dateTime = DateTime.now();
  final userId = user.id;
  final path = '$userId/$dateTime';
  uploadImage(
    onSelected: (file) {
      fb
          .storage()
          .refFromURL('gs://your-app.appspot.com/')
          .child(path)
          .put(file)
          .future
          .then((_) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user.id)
            .update({'photo_url': path});
      });
    },
  );
```

This code is extracted form a Github [repo](https://github.com/happyharis/profile_picture_firebase/tree/answer) if you want to take a deeper look.